# Trying to set up GeoServer for GeoMesa Hbase on EMR S3

Tags: geoserver, geomesa

I am running [GeoMesa Hbase on AWS S3](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/tutorials/geomesa-hbase-s3-on-aws.html). I am able to ingest / export data from inside the cluster with geomesa-hbase ingest / export but I am trying to acces the data remotely. I have installed GeoServer (on the same Master node where GeoMesa is running if that is relevant) but I have difficulty with providing GeoServer the correct JARs to acces GeoMesa. I can find the list of JARs that I should provide to GeoServer [here](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/hbase/install.html#install-hbase-geoserver) but I am not sure how or where to collect them. I have tried using the install-hadoop.sh & install-hbase.sh shell scripts in the /opt/geomesa/bin folder to install the HBase, Hadoop and Zookeeper JARs into GeoServers’ WEB-INF/lib folder, but if I change the Hadoop, Zookeeper & Hbase version in these shell scripts to be the same as the versions running on my cluster it does not find any JARS.

What I tried: One of the GeoMesa distributions contained a shell script 'install.dependencies.sh' which I used to collect the JARs listed [here](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/hbase/install.html#installing-geomesa-hbase-in-geoserver) (but with versions corresponding to my setup). But when I try to add a new Data store in GeoServer I get an class not found error.

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
    ... 112 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ctc/wstx/io/InputBootstrapper
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.data.HBaseDataStoreFactory$.canProcess(HBaseDataStoreFactory.scala:138)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.data.HBaseDataStoreFactory.canProcess(HBaseDataStoreFactory.scala:94)
    at org.vfny.geoserver.util.DataStoreUtils.aquireFactory(DataStoreUtils.java:95)
    at org.vfny.geoserver.util.DataStoreUtils.getDataAccess(DataStoreUtils.java:59)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getDataStore(ResourcePool.java:626)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.DataStoreInfoImpl.getDataStore(DataStoreInfoImpl.java:33)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.store.DataAccessNewPage.onSaveDataStore(DataAccessNewPage.java:89)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.store.AbstractDataAccessPage$1.onSubmit(AbstractDataAccessPage.java:173)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxSubmitLink$1.onSubmit(AjaxSubmitLink.java:111)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior$AjaxFormSubmitter.onSubmit(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:215)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1309)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:976)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:797)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:171)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:155)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:601)
    ... 117 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ctc.wstx.io.InputBootstrapper
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    ... 133 more
```

I am running everything on an EMR 6.2.0 release version (which comes with Hadoop 3.2.1, Hbase 2.2.6 and Zookeeper 3.4.14). On top of the cluster I am running GeoMesa 3.0.0-m0 with GeoServer 2.17 but I have also tried GeoMesa 2.4.0 with GeoServer 2.15. I’m fine with switching in either the EMR release version or GeoMesa/Server if that makes things easier.